# How can we work with QGIS Server on Windows?

Tags: windows, qgis-server

I want to work with QGIS Server on Windows. I have not information about properties in this area. Where should I start?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be information available for how to start working with **QGIS Server** on **Windows** at the **[QGIS Wiki](http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/wiki/QGIS_Server_Tutorial)**.

In particular this **[blog posting](http://anitagraser.com/2012/04/06/qgis-server-on-windows7-step-by-step/)** by @Underdark.